# Tapestry: Need to set column width in jquery/datatable

Tags: jquery, datatable, tapestry, column-width

I am using jquery/datatable. I have a column,Action that contains 3 hyperlink images. Right now, the 3 images is sometimes rendered on 2 separate line. I need them to be on 1 line. I think I need to set the column width. How do I do that? 
Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution already. I need to add css white-space:nowrap; in a div surrounding the images.
Here is the code fragment

```
<div style="white-space:nowrap;">
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do this with the css script :

if you column like this :

```
<div class="fixedWidth">
 <a href="#">link 1</a>
 <a href="#">link 2</a>
 <a href="#">link 3</a>
</div>
```

you can create the css script like this :

```
.fixedWidth{
 width : 200px !important;
}
```

try the another width until the view is correct

Comment: I am using jquery/datatable. The column header is the same for all columns. It is <div class="DataTables_sort_wrapper">

Comment: you can add another class in certain column, like <div class="DataTables_sort_wrapper fixedWidth">

Comment: if you can't put another class "fixedWidth" in the <div class="DataTables_sort_wrapper">, you can put the class in the tag <th> thead table, like <th class="fixedWidth">Action</th>

Comment: Hi, when using jquery/datatable, a table is automatically generated for you. So I cannot change/insert additional class info.

Comment: Ok, turns out I can insert additional <div> into the jquery/datatable. So I am giving you a +1 vote. Thanks